# Cumulative sum of first occurence of consecutive True values in a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have a Pandas dataframe columns A, B, C and D. I would like the Desired Column as follows:

Grouping by ['A','B','C'], I would like the Desired Column to show the cumulative sum of the **FIRST CONSECUTIVE** *True* values in column D.

| A | B | C | D | Desired Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | AAA | 001 | False | 0 |
| 100 | AAA | 001 | False | 0 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | True | 1 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | True | 2 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | True | 3 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | False | 3 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | True | 3 |
| 300 | CCC | 099 | False | 0 |
| 300 | CCC | 099 | True | 0 |

A False value stops the cumulative sum in a group, and any True values after that False are not considered.

I want to use this table to calculate an aggregate one:

| A | B | C | Max(Desired Column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | AAA | 001 | 0 |
| 200 | BBB | 055 | 3 |
| 300 | CCC | 099 | 0 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cummin` to mark all values after `False` as `False` and then calculate `cumsum`:

```
df['Desired Column'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).D.transform(lambda x: x.cummin().cumsum())

df
     A    B   C      D  Desired Column
0  100  AAA   1  False               0
1  100  AAA   1  False               0
2  200  BBB  55   True               1
3  200  BBB  55   True               2
4  200  BBB  55   True               3
5  200  BBB  55  False               3
6  200  BBB  55   True               3
7  300  CCC  99  False               0
8  300  CCC  99   True               0
```

If you only need the aggregate column, then you can just find the index of the first `False` with `argmin`:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False).D.agg(
  lambda x: len(x) if x.all() else x.argmin()
)

     A    B   C  D
0  100  AAA   1  0
1  200  BBB  55  3
2  300  CCC  99  0
```

Comment: Can `cummin` be replaced with `cumprod` in this case?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea, but with `cumprod`, then I saw your answer. TIL about `cummin` :)

Comment: I think that's expected. In that case the first consecutive `True` will have only one `True` value, so it should `sum` to 1. @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny IMO, one `True` value can still be considered as a sequence of length one. But we can wait for OP's clarification.

Comment: I added an answer with a variation of your approach (`cummin().cumsum()`) to account for at least two consecutive `True`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I added a group to your example data to include a case where the group starts with one not consecutive `True` followed by `False`.

[`df.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html)`.min()` does the same as [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html), but `min_periods` controls after how many rows to start the accumulation. `bfill` fills `nan` values accordingly in the first row of every group.

```
df['actual'] = (df.groupby(['A','B','C']).D
                  .apply(lambda x: x.expanding(min_periods=2)
                                    .min()
                                    .bfill()
                                    .cumsum())
                  .astype('int'))

assert df.actual.equals(df.Desired), 'different results, try again'
df
```

Output

```
      A    B    C      D  Desired  actual
0   100  AAA    1  False        0       0
1   100  AAA    1  False        0       0
2   200  BBB   55   True        1       1
3   200  BBB   55   True        2       2
4   200  BBB   55   True        3       3
5   200  BBB   55  False        3       3
6   200  BBB   55   True        3       3
7   300  CCC   99  False        0       0
8   300  CCC   99   True        0       0
9   400  DDD  199   True        0       0
10  400  DDD  199  False        0       0
```

Preparing the example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
A,B,C,D,Desired
100,AAA,1,False,0
100,AAA,1,False,0
200,BBB,55,True,1
200,BBB,55,True,2
200,BBB,55,True,3
200,BBB,55,False,3
200,BBB,55,True,3
300,CCC,99,False,0
300,CCC,99,True,0
400,DDD,199,True,0
400,DDD,199,False,0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df
```

Output

```
      A    B    C      D  Desired
0   100  AAA    1  False        0
1   100  AAA    1  False        0
2   200  BBB   55   True        1
3   200  BBB   55   True        2
4   200  BBB   55   True        3
5   200  BBB   55  False        3
6   200  BBB   55   True        3
7   300  CCC   99  False        0
8   300  CCC   99   True        0
9   400  DDD  199   True        0
10  400  DDD  199  False        0
```

Get the max row for every group

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).actual.max().reset_index()
```

Output

```
     A    B    C  actual
0  100  AAA    1       0
1  200  BBB   55       3
2  300  CCC   99       0
3  400  DDD  199       0
```

Comment: Great demo for expanding. However this would also increase the count if there is another separate sequence of `True` after the 1st sequence. So you might still need `cummin` to mark everything after the 1st `False` as `False`

Comment: It only counts `True` untill the first `False` (just like `cummin`), regardless of which values follow in the group. If the expanding window contains one `False` `min` is `False` overall. To be shure I tested it with added `True` rows to group `BBB`. A drawback is that `min` will be computed several times for the same values. The complexity is `~O(n^2)` vs `O(n)` with `cummin`.

Comment: Got it. Cool solution.  +1